# Total memory vs memory per CPU vs memory per process

Tags: process, memory, cpu

I have troubles understanding memory (RAM) specifications of CPUs. Just as an example, the [Xeon Gold 6144](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124943/intel-xeon-gold-6144-processor-24-75m-cache-3-50-ghz.html) specs give a maximal memory size of 768GB. If I have a mainboard with two CPU sockets and 24 memory banks which I fill up with 64GB modules each so that I have 1.5TB of memory in total, then how much memory can a single process consume/access? 768GB or the full 1.5TB?

Comment: Is this a Unix question. Maybe if you include numa.

Comment: Wasn't sure about the right forum. I've posted it on superuser now.

Comment: Also include if the processors are configured with symmetric memory access. If not also tell us if you are using numa.